# Difference between calling getActivity().startActivity(); and startActivity(); inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

start Activity from inside a Fragment 
can be done with both codes :

```
startActivity(Intent);

getActivity().startActivity();
```

what is the difference ??

**Note** :
I know the difference when it becomes to `startActivityForResult();` 
so please don't post any thing relates to this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing.  [The `Fragment` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) are pretty clear on this:

> `public void startActivity (Intent intent)`
>
> Call `startActivity(Intent)` from the fragment's containing Activity.

Comment: I am a couch potato developer so I am lazy to look after it in the documentation . but I try to give some credit(s) to someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference:

Fragment#startActivity() check if mHost == null throw "Fragment this is not attached to Activity" exception. If you use `getActivity().startActivity()` it will return a nullable value. If mHost is null you will get NullPointException i.