# Kotlin: how to open activity from fragment with button in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

How can I open a new activity with a button inside the fragment layout?.

I have tried this

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        button25.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent (getActivity(), settingActivity::class.java)
            getActivity().startActivity(intent)
        }
        return view
    }
```

Any idea of how I can start a new activity inside a fragment?

Comment: That should work. What happens when you click your button?

Comment: It should open an activity

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759668/difference-between-calling-getactivity-startactivity-and-startactivity-i

Comment: I am really new to this I couldn't get it

Comment: you can call `startActivity(intent)` without the need of `getActivity()` if you have any issues please update the question with the error you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your button's listener after your fragment view is created, which gives callback in **onViewCreated**

**onCreateView** is called when Fragment's view is in the process of creating and you are accessing your fragment view's child before creating it.

It should be done like,

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   button25.setOnClickListener {
      activity?.let{
      val intent = Intent (it, Main::class.java)
      it.startActivity(intent)
    }

  }
}
```